# AWS Redshift table-valued function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm testing AWS Redshift as an option for building Data Warehouse.

According to document, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html

I've found that I can create scalar user-defined function with python.

But I'm wondering that if Redshift supports **table-valued** function? I have done some research but haven't found any information about that.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Return a Scalar Array! then split part you way to table land.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udfArray ()
  RETURNS text IMMUTABLE AS
  $$
    return 'Matthew,5,44'
  $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT
    Split_Part(t1.scalarOut, ',',1) val1,
    Split_Part(t1.scalarOut, ',',2) val2,
    Split_Part(t1.scalarOut, ',',3) val3
FROM
    (SELECT udfArray () scalarOut) t1;
```